# Encoding issue asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, encoding

I have a file in notepad, saves ad Ansi encoding with two URLs:

http://www.odinklik.ru/site​.aspx?​site=korney_​chukovsky

http://www.odinklik.ru/site.aspx?site=korney_chukovsky

As you can see from the paste - one of them is looking "weird".
It is changed to: 
"http://www.odinklik.ru/site%E2%80%8B.aspx?%E2%80%8Bsite=korney_%E2%80%8Bchukovsky"

When i copy it in the browser. What is happening here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code E2 80 8B is the UTF-8 code for the character Zero Width Space, but this is not a character that exists in an ANSI character set.

Either you have some other obscure spacing character that is translated into a Zero Width Space when you copy the text, or the file is actually not saved as ANSI after all.

Comment: Notepad says it is ANSI and the text but if I open it in TextPad i indeed see some other characters. These URLs with the strange character show up as "404" in Google webmaster tools - can I strip them somehow?

Comment: @Pleun: Even if the characters are not visible, they are still characters, and can be deleted. I don't know where you get the URL from, but if possible you should try to fix it at the source rather than trying to fix it by filtering out characters afterwards.

Comment: Maybe got it from Facebook? https://plus.google.com/114723964985237592593/posts/H7gFiLek5Bs

Comment: No it is not facebook,it is some web indexing agent so we know now it is not a problem for our users but it is still a pain in the ...