# What kind of URL encoding is this?

Tags: python

I have the encoded URL

```
http://blahblah.com/s%E2%80%8Btart/DEE-G%E2%80%8B6F-W4A-2N1%E2%80%8B5
```

for

```
http://blahblah.com/start/DEE-G6F-W4A-2N15
```

What kind of encoding is this and how to I convert it in Python?

Comment: I do not understand what is going on in this question, it seems that `%E2%80%8B` is just randomly inserted into your URL. - How did this happen? What have you tried to do to convert it? How did you get from A->B or from B->A ?

Comment: This happens when copying an email in IE and pasting it in Chrome or FF. :-/

Comment: Similar question and problem(%E2%80%8B) here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315422/encoding-issue-asp-net

Answer (score 3):

Edit: (due to conversation with @interjay):

`%E2%80%8B` represents a `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`. Those probably shouldn't be there. You could remove them with `str.replace`:

```
In [135]: 'http://blahblah.com/s%E2%80%8Btart/DEE-G%E2%80%8B6F-W4A-2N1%E2%80%8B5'.replace('%E2%80%8B', '')
Out[135]: 'http://blahblah.com/start/DEE-G6F-W4A-2N15'
```

---

In general, quoted URLs can be unquoted using [urllib.unquote](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.unquote):

```
In [6]: import urllib

In [7]: print(urllib.unquote('http://blahblah.com/s%E2%80%8Btart/DEE-G%E2%80%8B6F-W4A-2N1%E2%80%8B5'))
http://blahblah.com/s​tart/DEE-G​6F-W4A-2N1​5
```

---

Here is how you can tell that `%E2%80%8B` represents a `ZERO WIDTH SPACE`:

```
In [18]: x = urllib.unquote('%E2%80%8B')

In [19]: y = x.decode('utf-8')

In [20]: import unicodedata as UD

In [21]: [UD.name(c) for c in y]
Out[21]: ['ZERO WIDTH SPACE']
```

Note that the unqoted URL includes ZERO WIDTH SPACEs:

```
In [4]: urllib.unquote('http://blahblah.com/s%E2%80%8Btart/DEE-G%E2%80%8B6F-W4A-2N1%E2%80%8B5')
Out[4]: 'http://blahblah.com/s\xe2\x80\x8btart/DEE-G\xe2\x80\x8b6F-W4A-2N1\xe2\x80\x8b5'
```

It seems like an odd thing to put in a URL...

Comment: This will leave the zero-width space in the string (although you can't see it when using `print`), which is probably not the right solution, as the URL is almost certainly not supposed to have a zero-width space in the middle of a word.

Comment: Given the URL, this is how it is unquoted in Python. Whether the given URL is correct is not the OP's question and not one we can answer since the URL is obviously made-up.

Comment: Part of answering a question is figuring out what the OP actually needs, as they may not exactly know themselves. In this case, unquoting the URL is obviously not it.

Comment: What do you think is the actual problem then?

Comment: Going by the OP's comment, the problem is probably with his webmail client or browser adding the zero-width space. If it can't be fixed in the source, the zero-width space probably needs to be removed rather than unquoted.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right; I jumped the gun on this one.